# Assign Values of an Array to each value of another array and submit in a JSON format in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two arrays, one having user ids and another having tags.
'''
["ELG001", "ELG002"]
["TG01", "TG02"]

'''
am supposed to submit to an endpoint that expects a json in this format
'''
"id_tags": [{
"id": "ELG001",
"tag": "TG01,TG02"
},
{
"id": "ELG002",
"tag": "TG01,TG02"
}
]
'''

How can I achieve to send the data in the expected format using map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a simple snippet for you below based on your question that you want the first array to be the id and just add the second array as tags for your json.

```js
const idArray = ["ELG001", "ELG002"];
const tagArray = ["TG01", "TG02"];
let tagArr = [];
idArray.forEach((el) => {
  tagArr.push({
    id: el,
    tag: tagArray.join(",")
  })
})
const tag = {
  id_tags: tagArr
}
console.log(tag);
```

Comment: what if it is required in this format                                                                                                                "id_tags": [{
        "id": "ELG001",
        "tag": "TG01"
    },
    {
        "id": "ELG001",
        "tag": "TG02"
    } {
        "id": "ELG002",
        "tag": "TG01"
    } {
        "id": "ELG002",
        "tag": "TG02"
    }
]

Comment: const idArray = ["ELG001", "ELG002"] // is supposed to be reporter Ids
const tagArray = ["TG01", "TG02"] // is supposed to hold selected tags
const tagArr = [];

idArray.forEach((el) => {
      tagArray.forEach((ll) =>{
        tagArr.push({reporter: el, tag: ll })
      })
    })
    const reporterTags = {
      reporter_tags: tagArr
    }
    console.log(reporterTags);